# Pandas fill missing values of a column based on the datetime values of another column

Tags: pandas, datetime, missing-data

Python newbie here, this is my first question. 
I tried to find a solution on similar SO questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51636583/set-column-value-based-on-indexed-datetime-filter), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49161120/pandas-python-set-value-of-one-column-based-on-value-in-another-column), and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920408/how-to-substitute-nan-values-of-a-column-based-on-the-values-of-another-column), but I think my problem is different.

Here's my situation: I have a quite large dataset with two columns: **Date** (datetime object), and **session_id** (integer). The timestamps refer to the moment where a certain action occurred during an online session.

My problem is that I have all the dates, but I am missing some of the corresponding session_id values. What I would like to do is to fill these missing values using the date column:

1. If the action occurred between the first and last date of a certain session, I would like to fill the missing value with the id of that session.
2. I would mark as '0' the session where the action occurred outside the range of any session -
3. and mark it as '-99' if it is not possible to associate the event to a single session, because it occurred during the time range of different session.

To give an example of my problem, let's consider the toy dataset below, where I have just three sessions: a, b, c. Session a and b registered three events, session c two. Moreover, I have three missing id values.

```
   |       DATE          |sess_id|
----------------------------------
 0 | 2018-01-01 00:19:01 | a    | 
 1 | 2018-01-01 00:19:05 | b    | 
 2 | 2018-01-01 00:21:07 | a    |
 3 | 2018-01-01 00:22:07 | b    | 
 4 | 2018-01-01 00:25:09 | c    |         
 5 | 2018-01-01 00:25:11 | Nan  |
 6 | 2018-01-01 00:27:28 | c    | 
 7 | 2018-01-01 00:29:29 | a    | 
 8 | 2018-01-01 00:30:35 | Nan  | 
 9 | 2018-01-01 00:31:16 | b    | 
10 | 2018-01-01 00:35:22 | Nan  | 
...

[Image_Timeline example][1]
```

This is what I would like to obtain:

```
   |       DATE          |sess_id|
----------------------------------
 0 | 2018-01-01 00:19:01 | a    | 
 1 | 2018-01-01 00:19:05 | b    | 
 2 | 2018-01-01 00:21:07 | a    |
 3 | 2018-01-01 00:22:07 | b    | 
 4 | 2018-01-01 00:25:09 | c    |         
 5 | 2018-01-01 00:25:11 | -99  |
 6 | 2018-01-01 00:27:28 | c    | 
 7 | 2018-01-01 00:29:29 | a    | 
 8 | 2018-01-01 00:30:35 | b    | 
 9 | 2018-01-01 00:31:16 | b    | 
10 | 2018-01-01 00:35:22 | 0    | 
...
```

In this way I will be able to recover at least some of the events without session code. 
I think that maybe the first thing to do is to compute two new columns showing the first and last time value for each session, something like that:

```
foo['last'] = foo.groupby('sess_id')['DATE'].transform(max) 
foo['firs'] = foo.groupby('SESSIONCODE')['DATE'].transform(min)
```

And then use first-last time value to check whether each event whose session id is unknown falls withing that range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition seems fine by me, but you can't apply it this way since your dataframe `foo` doens't have the same size as your `groupby` dataframe. What you could do is map the values like this:

```
foo['last'] = foo.sess_id.map(foo.groupby('sess_id').DATE.max())
foo['first'] = foo.sess_id.map(foo.groupby('sess_id').DATE.min())
```

But I don't think it's necessary, you can just use the groupby dataframe as such.

A way to solve your problem could be to look for the missing values in `sess_id` column, and apply a custom function to the corresponding dates:

```
def my_custom_function(time):
    current_sessions = my_agg.loc[(my_agg['min']<time) & (my_agg['max']>time)]
    count = len(current_sessions)
    if count == 0:
        return 0
    if count > 1:
        return -99
    return current_sessions.index[0]

my_agg = foo.groupby('sess_id').DATE.agg([min,max])
foo.loc[foo.sess_id.isnull(),'sess_id'] = foo.loc[foo.sess_id.isnull(),'DATE'].apply(my_custom_function)
```

Output:

```
    DATE                    sess_id
0   2018-01-01 00:19:01     a
1   2018-01-01 00:19:05     b
2   2018-01-01 00:21:07     a
3   2018-01-01 00:22:07     b
4   2018-01-01 00:25:09     c
5   2018-01-01 00:25:11     -99
6   2018-01-01 00:27:28     c
7   2018-01-01 00:29:29     a
8   2018-01-01 00:30:35     b
9   2018-01-01 00:31:16     b
10  2018-01-01 00:35:22     0
```

I think it performs what you are looking for, though the output you posted in your question seems to contain typos.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Indeed, there was a small typo in the output, i'm going to fix it. Could I just ask you to clarify what the last return (return current_sessions.index[0]) does?

Comment: No problem, in case that there is exactly one session which match the test (ie which begins before the given time and ends after), we retrieve its name. Indeed the data frame `my_agg` is given by a groupby on `sess_id` which means its index is composed of values from `sess_id`. When we only have one session in its index, `current_sessions.index[0]` allows us to retrieve this `sess_id` value. Is it clear?

Comment: in `my_custom_function` I have some if statements. These are here to check how many sessions are open at the time we're looking at. The first `if count == 0` activates when no session is open, the second `if count > 1` is for when you have multiple open sessions, so that when you reach the last `return` you must have only one open session.

Comment: It's clear. So, let's say that we have more session in the index, as more than just one match the test, what could we do? Maybe change to if count ==1 return current_session.index? In any case thank you for the clear explanation, I really appreciated it.

Comment: It depends on what your are trying to return, I understood from your question that if you couldn't link the time to a unique session, you should get `-99` as a result. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, you were right. Thank you for your teaching, they really helped me much.